# How can I improve my FPS in Assassins Creed 2?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2

Assassins Creed 2 is notorious for being resource-intensive, and particularly for my computer, it's bad.  Even tweaking down the ingame settings to the lowest, lowering my resolution to the min, I can only run the game at a very unstable 10 fps.

Is there any way I can modify any files to give me some sort of performance boost?

Comment: Don't fight it, get a new computer (or upgrade some parts)... AC2 wasn't terribly resource intensive. If yours can't handle it, then your computer is just too old. A $50-70 video card nowadays should be able to handle this easy. Make the investment or go bigger.

Comment: I have a...craptop.  Imagine an Intel Atom....with the best Nvidia card out there.  The processor just cant get to speed.  NOt to mention I don't exactly have enough funds to get a new laptop/pc.  Are there any .cfg tweaks I can dO/

Comment: An Atom is for "netbook" class laptops, they're are not meant for gaming.

Comment: Exactly.  That's basically my computer.  Whoever made it (specifically HP) thought'd it'd be a great idea to do that, and evidently, I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

I regret to inform you that there usually are very few magic tricks one can use to gain extreme boosts in performance. I am no tuning expert but when your computer struggles to even maintain very low amounts of frames per second there is simply not enough computing resources to go around and as a consequence, very little room for any optimizations. From your comments it sounds like your processor is the bottle-neck, and to increase speed would require you to disable CPU-intensive processes within the game, which may not be possible. Reducing your graphics settings may not have any noticeable effect on fps if your GPU manages just fine.

Therefore I would recommend you to get a computer, and if that is not possible, play some less CPU-intensive games until you possess the funds to acquire a new computer.

Comment: Yeah, I"ll have to save for about 200 years, then I'll probably get a new coputer.